# Looping over futures not working same as ExecutorCompletionService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
responseFromAllThreads () {
    Collection <String> response;
    String result;
    for (Future f : futuresList) { //java.util.concurrent.Future
       result = (String) f.get();
       response.add(result);
    }
  return response;
}
```

when I make the call to `responseFromAllThreads()` I expect that my response will GUARANTEE to contain the corresponding results from all futures.  But instead, every once in a while, I was finding the duplication of task result in the response collection returned by `responseFromAllThreads`!  From java docs `f.get() "Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result."`.

When I use `ExecutorCompletionService` response collection seems to be returning fine at all times.  Please could someone explain why it did not work with looping over futures directly and if its a correct measure to use ExecustionCompletionService?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], how you use each, how you construct the future list.

Comment: the problem is elsewhere, it cannot be related to the `get()` method that may return a result from another future, it is probably because in your list you have simply twice the same future, or 2 different futures executing the same task or 2 different futures executing the different tasks that have the same result.

Comment: Where do you add `Future` objects to the `futuresList`? Please post the code

Comment: "I was finding the duplication of task result in the response collection returned by responseFromAllThreads" - Can you post your code and output?